# SharePoint 2013 In allitems.aspx How Do I get the list title and Name

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I am trying to mimic the Alert Me functionality as the business only wants Alert Me and Send a link.  In Alert Me I am trying to get the current list's Name and Title when my javascript code is in the allitems.aspx page of my document library.  All of the examples I can find assume you know the title of the list already.

Answer (score 1):

At least the following options could be used to determine list properties (like `Title`) in List View page (`AllItems.aspx`)

### Using `SP.ListOperation.Selection` namespace

[SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList() Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff410971%28v=office.14%29.aspx) gets the ID of the list being selected:

```
var listId = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();
```

The following example demonstrates how to retrieve list by its Id via CSOM (JavaScript):

```
(function(){

  var listId = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList(); //selected List Id
  var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
  var web = context.get_web();
  var list = web.get_lists().getById(listId);

  context.load(list);
  context.executeQueryAsync(
     function() {
       //print List properties
       console.log(list.get_title());
     },
     function(sender,args){
        console.log(args.get_message());
     }
  );
})();
```

### Using `_spPageContextInfo` structure

`_spPageContextInfo` object is rendered in every SharePoint page and contains property `_spPageContextInfo.pageListId` that stores the current List Id:

```
var listId = _spPageContextInfo.pageListId;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  does not _spPageContextInfo.pageListId point to the pages (or sitepages) list ?  If I am on an allitems.aspx page does _spPageContextInfo.pageListId point to the actual list rather than the pages list ? Thanks Nigel

Comment: Good question indeed, but pageListId property  points to the actual list.